# "this is undefined error" in JS using Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-maps, web

I can't seem to figure out this problem where the below code works when the "for loop" is disabled, and the attributes "locations" and "startAddress" are just simple strings. But if they are not, I am getting a **"this is undefined"** error when the ajax post request is submitted. Do you have any ideas why would this be? Any leads would be appreciated.

```
// create an event handler for the save route button

$("#saveRouteButton").click(function(){
    var saveRouteName = $("#saveRouteNameField").val();
    if (!saveRouteName) {
        alert("Please supply a proper name to be submitted to the database");
    } else {
        var routeLength = directionsDisplay.getDirections().routes[0].legs.length;
        var returnRoute = {
            alias: null,
            locations : [], // make this a string - it works!
            startAddresses : [], // make this a string - it works!
        };

        // disable this loop - it works!
        for (var i = 0; i < routeLength; i++){
            returnRoute.locations[i] = directionsDisplay.getDirections().routes[0].legs[i].start_location
            returnRoute.startAddresses[i] = directionsDisplay.getDirections().routes[0].legs[i].start_address
        };
        route_info = returnRoute;
        route_info.alias = saveRouteName;

        //test to see if the variables are set, they are!
        alert(route_info.alias);
        alert(route_info.locations);
        alert($.isPlainObject(route_info))

        $.ajax({
            url: "save_route/", 
            type: "POST",
            data : route_info, 
            success: function(data){
                        if (data != "None") {
                            $("#savedRoutesList").append('<li class="savedRoutesListItem">' 
                            + data + '</li>');
                        }
                        else {alert("You need to enter a route name");}
                    }
            });
    }
    return false;
});
```

the error originates from the : [google maps main js](http://maps.gstatic.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/api-3/16/13/main.js) - line 13

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just check the route Length value,whether it is giving correct value or not?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I have checked for the routeLength and it seems to be valid. And also those alert() functions I have before the $.ajax seems to be yielding expected values as well. It still fails though.